# rails 5.2.2 spree 3.6.4 unable to change logo image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I'm trying to use this path to my image /vendor/assets/images/spree/frontend/logo/spree_50.png but the image displays as symbol indicating the resource wasn't available When I inspect it I see the path to the image is right

Comment: Can you show us where/how you use it in your application? Do you create an `<img>` tag? Do you use it in JavaScript? A bit more context would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

The path you supplied does not follow the conventions. Put the image in the following path:

```
vendor/assets/images/logo/spree_50.png
```

Comment: This does not work. What is the path in development?